# Ubuntu Core 16 "snap find" only shows 5 snaps available

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

On a new install of Ubuntu Core on a Pi 3 I have 3 snaps installed, and only 5 available from snap?

root@localhost:~# snap list 
Name        Version                   Rev   Developer  Notes
core        16-2.26.3+git212.34125a5  2031  canonical  -
pi2-kernel  4.4.0-1051.52             30    canonical  -
pi3         16.04-0.5                 19    canonical  -

root@localhost:~# snap find
Name               Version       Developer     Notes  Summary
docker             17.03.1-ce-0  docker-inc    -      The docker app deployment mechanism
lxd                2.13          canonical     -      System container manager and API
rocketchat-server  0.56.0        rocketchat    -      Group chat server for 100s,  installed in seconds.
nextcloud          11.0.3snap3   nextcloud     -      Nextcloud Server
hugo               0.21          hugo-authors  -      Fast and Flexible Static Site Generator

I have connectivity to the net, am logged in via ssh, and able to "snap login".. Im just not seeing what I expect to be a reasonable set of snaps..

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere in the snapcraft forum that that's an artificial limit on the pattern-less `snap find`.  If you try something like `snap find ca` you will find packages not found in the pattern-less `find`, so the command is working fine